# SQL: transform full-text search into like construction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I've got stored procedure that performs search using full-text indexes in general case. But I can't build full-text index for one field, and I need to use LIKE construction.

So, the problem is: parameter could be

> "a*" or "b*"

like parameter for `CONTAINS` command.

Сan anyone give a good solution, how to transform this parameter for `LIKE` construction.

Thank you.

P.S: I use `MSSQL Server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone!

Unfortunately expression parsing is not enough for general case.

I use regular expressions in MS SQL SERVER

> http://anastasiosyal.com/POST/2008/07/05/REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS-IN-MS-SQL-SERVER-USING-CLR.ASPX

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the full-text search constructs you want to support, this is generally impossible.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx#queries), full-text search syntax on SQL Server supports these constructs:

> One or more specific words or phrases (simple term)

something along LIKE '%[,;.-()!? ]Term[,;.-()!? ]%'

> A word or a phrase where the words begin with specified text (prefix term)

something along LIKE '%[,;.-()!? ]Term%'

> Inflectional forms of a specific word (generation term)

Not possible

> A word or phrase close to another word or phrase (proximity term)

Not possible

> Synonymous forms of a specific word (thesaurus)

Not possible

> Words or phrases using weighted values (weighted term)

Not possible

Those which I have marked "not possible" can't really be translated to LIKE queries, but of course you could get inventive (using your own stemming algorithm for inflectional forms, or your own thesaurus for synonyms) to support at least some of those.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, you will probably need to use dynamic SQL.

Here is a way you can get the correct WHERE clause, given that input:

```
declare @str varchar(255) = '"a*" or "b*"';

with const as (select 'col' as col)
select col+' like '+replace(replace(REPLACE(@str, '"', ''''), '*', '%'), 'or ', 'or '+COL+' like ') as WhereClause
from const
```

The "const" is just a table with one column to specify your column name.  It allows it to be specified in one place.

This just does replaces to get the correct syntax for LIKE.  Of course, this would be more complex to support more functionality from CONTAINS.